# ODP.NET for Oracle in Windows 2003 Server 64-bits

Tags: oracle, windows-server-2003, odp.net

We have ASP.NET framework 3.5 hosted in Windows 2003 Server 32-bits.
Database: Oracle 10gR2 in Windows 2003 Server 64-bits
We should use ODP.NET 10.2.0.3.

Questions:
- Is ODP.NET 10.2.0.3 made to connect to a 32bit or 64bit Oracle database?
- Is the same for Oracle Client?

Answer (score 1):

The bitness of the client and server do not need to match.

SQL*Net takes care of all of the communication issues.

Comment: Even if Oracle 10g is in Linux 64-bit and my .NET is in a Windows 2003 Server 32-bit, it doesn't matter for ODP.NET 10.2? I'm aware that I should install on Windows Server 2003:
- ODP.NET 10.2
- Oracle Client for Windows 32-bits

Comment: The bitness and the operating system are handled by Oracle.  The only thing you need to worry about is the version.  As features are added to the server, some of the earlier versions of the client get blocked, since they don't support some of the features.